# Speed at which C prints a string

Tags: c, linux

How would I go about writing a program in C that repeatedly prints out a string, but at different speeds.  Basically, how to increase time between each return in a loop?

Comment: C doesn't provide a standard delay mechanism (unless you count busy waiting for the time to change).  The right solution depends on your platform, so you should way which one you are targeting.

Comment: You could try the sleep(t) function from time.h. It suspends execution for t seconds.

Comment: @Cameron: And on eg. Windows, this will give you a compiler error.

Comment: `#ifdef WIN32 /*Windows code here*/  #else /*Linux code here*/ #endif`  or just look for a cross platform library (which will most likely do this under the hood but makes _your_ code nicer.)

Comment: Please *edit your question* to improve it, e.g. by telling us on which platform (which operating system, perhaps which processor) is your program running and by motivating your question (why are you asking?).

Comment: @FatalError, modern C since C11 has a standard delay mechanism, `thrd_sleep`. Unfortunately this is not yet implemented everywhere :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I go about writing a program in C that repeatedly prints out a string, but at different speeds.

You can merly increase a program's speed. But you can delay it more or less.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  while (1)
  {
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    <delay more or less here>
  }
}
```

Under Linux the [`sleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) system call can be used to delay a program's execution by seconds.

Comment: Perhaps mention `nanosleep` for higher precision (but not necessarily more accurate) timing. (PS just saw the downvote, that wasn't me.)

Comment: `nanosleep` is POSIX so it is standardized and widely supported. C11 has the equivalent `thrd_sleep`, which will be the right interface in the near future. It can be easily emulated by `nanosleep` if the platform doesn't provide it.